# Ajax gets as result whole page from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call php function using ajax. Ajax is called from php with onclick function in button. But instead of value, that the called function add_player returns, i get whole page exec.php.
Thank you for your help.

index.php

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="dragon_javascript.js"></script>';
echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
echo '<input type="text" name="jmeno" id="jm" value="Zadej jmeno uzivatele">';
echo '<input type="text" name="prijmeni" id="pr" value="Zadej celkove body uzivatele">';
echo '<button onclick="javascript:add_user()">pridej uzivatele</button>';
```

javascript

```
function  add_user() {
    var player_name =  document.getElementById('jm').value;
    var overall_points =  document.getElementById('pr').value;
    $.ajax({
        url:"exec.php?action=add_player",
        type:'POST',
        datatype:'json',
        data:{
            player_name:player_name,
            overall_points:overall_points
        },
    success: function(result){
        
        if(result=='success') alert('it worked');
        else alert('did not work');
        alert(result);

    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('did not workaaa');

    }
    });
}
```

exec.php

```
function add_player($player_name, $overall_points)
{
// connect to database
      dibi::connect([ 
    'driver'   => 'mysqli',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'draci_sipka',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
  ]);
    try 
    {
      dibi::query('INSERT INTO player VALUES(1,Null,%s,%i)',$player_name,intval($overall_points));
    } 
  catch (DibiException $e) 
  {
      return 'mistake';
  }
  return 'success';
     
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not an error page? What does the response actually look like?

Comment: Does "the whole page" mean that it returns the PHP code?

Comment: You don't call PHP functions by passing a GET parameter with the same name. That's not how it works (and it would be a HEAVY security thread if that worked). You'd rather use something like `if (isset($_GET["param_name"])) { switch ($_GET["param_name"]) { /* ... */ case "asdf": your_function(); break; /* ... */`

Comment: Yes, "the whole page" means that it returns php code of exec.php. I'll try that solution with session.

Comment: If it returns the raw PHP code (instead of the result of executing that code) then that means that PHP is not installed and running correctly in your webserver

Comment: If that's the full and entire contents of exec.php, it has several problems, starting with not having `<?php ... ?>` tags that would tell the server that it's PHP code. Secondly what Chris said, all you have is a function but you never call it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that somewhere, but not shown, `index.php` has ...

```
<?php
...
?>
```

... surrounding the `echo` statements. **If not, make it so.**

If you are returning the entire code of `exec.php` as your result, that suggests that you do *not* have your code enclosed within `<?php ... ?>` tags. That is problem number one. The second problem is how you are retrieving the actual parameters passed to the script. The third problem is how you are trying to send back the results.

**exec.php**

```
<?php

/* get the two passed parameters: */
$add_player = $_REQUEST['player_name']; // works for get or post requests (or $_POST['player_name'], which is post-specific
$overall_point = $_REQUEST['overall_point];

/* do computations: */
// actual computations omitted here
$result = 'success'; // or possibly 'mistake'

/* send back the result */
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // describe the mime-type of the result
echo $result; // write out the result
```

The final `?>` may be omitted. You can also test whether the expected parameters have been passed with:

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['player_name'])) {
    // error code
}
```

*Ultimately it is what your script *writes out* that is considered the "return value" for the Ajax request. The PHP interpreter outputs whatever is not within `<?php ... ?>` tags so when you omitted those tags, your source program itself was written out (with a default mime-type) and considered the return value.*